# Error when inject dependency by using DelegatingFilterProxy

Tags: spring-mvc, web.xml, servlet-filters

I am trying to inject dependency into a servlet filter by using spring bean:

I define the filter in `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And I inject an instance in another bean section in `***-***-context.xml`:

```
<bean id="myFilter" class="com.filter.MyFilter">
  <property name="runPolicy" ref="RunPolicy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="RunPolicy" class="com.***.***.RunPolicyImpl"/>
```

However, I got error:

`failed myFilter: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myFilter' is defined`

What I am missing? Thank you!

P.S. I have spring listener and context-param in the web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the .xml file you are using for declaring the beans in not in classpath. Did you import your *****-***-context.xml** in applicationContext.xml.

Comment: actually, I did not find the applicationContext.xml in the module... But since the `***-context.xml` was created before, it should be imported into spring's root context somewhere.

Comment: you are right. I import ***context.xml into spring's root application context. Then it works. Thank you